# ActionScript 3.0 Randomize array, display number, and splice that number

Tags: arrays, random, actionscript

So I am building a deck of cards.  I have them blocked out, and appearing correctly on the screen.  Now I need to build an array with numbers 1-16, and display them randomly on the cards without duplicating any numbers.  My main problem is I can't figure out how to display the random numbers on the cards.  I have filled the array, got the cards displaying correctly, I can even display the numbers in order, but can't figure out the code to display the numbers randomly.  Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I have so far, which displays the cards with numerically ordered numbers.

```
var numberOfColumns=8;
var cardNumber:Array = new Array();



        //---"for" function to display card columns---\\

for(var i:int = 1; i < 17; i++) {
var card = new Card(); 
cardNumber[i]= i;

card.x = ((i-1) % numberOfColumns) * 70; 
card.y = (Math.floor ((i-1)/numberOfColumns) * 80);

 card.cardTxt.text = i;

trace(i);//trace card count in Output

addChild(card);//add object to display list
}

trace(cardNumber);
```

Comment: This is a really good question for a newcomer - you've shown everything you've tried and where you're at, and even managed to format your code. Great work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution ( definetly not the best ) would be to fill another array with only indexes and then randomly splice it, like this :

```
var cardCount:int = 17;
var indexesArray:Array = [];

for(var j:int = 1; j < cardCount; j++)
    indexesArray.push(j)

for(var i:int = 1; i < cardCount; i++) {

    var card = new Card();

    //Use a random index inside the array length
    var randIndex:int = Math.round(Math.random()*indexesArray.length);

    cardNumber[i]= indexesArray[idIndex];

    //Strip out our used index so we can't use it again
    indexesArray.splice( randIndex, 1 );

    //... your code
}
```

However I'm pretty sure some logic freak can come up with a more optimized/clean solution, and avoid the need for a second array.

Comment: Wow I realize this question is quite old, I was browsing the unanswered ones... Hopefully it'll help someone :)